# Can't connect to Mongodb with SSL

Tags: mongodb, openssl, windows-10

- Windows 10 Pro x64
- Mongodb 4.4
- Compass GUI

I set up Mongodb as normal (no security) and verified everything was working. Now trying to add TLS/SSL. I followed the instructions at:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/appendix/security/appendixA-openssl-ca/
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/appendix/security/appendixB-openssl-server/

No errors. Everything succeeded. Verified the pems with:

```
openssl verify -CAfile mongodb.pem mongodb01.pem

mongodb01.pem: OK
```

Updated my config file with:

```
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: mongodb01.xxx.com
  tls:
    mode: requireTLS
    certificateKeyFile: C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.4\bin\mongodb01.pem
    CAFile: C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.4\bin\mongodb.pem
```

The CA cert was created for *.xxx.com and the server cert was created for mongodb01.xxx.com. NOTE: mongodb01.xxx.com is faked in my hosts file to 127.0.0.1. I've done this many times before and the fake dns name trick does work when its all on the same machine.

I then run mongodb with:

```
mongod --config "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.4\bin\mongod.cfg"
```

But when I try:

```
openssl s_client -connect mongodb01.xxx.com:27017

verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify error:num=21:unable to verify the first certificate
```

EDIT:

So I made SOME progress. I don't think MongoDB is picking up the CAFile. When I added the root cert and the intermediate cert into the mongodb01.pem (and all 3 signed with the same key), then the cert chain passes, but its returning a self signed cert error (as expected).

I haven't tried calling it from Java yet, I was trying to get it to work in Compass first. However, Compass complains about the self signed cert. I tried putting the certs in the my trusted store, but Compass still refuses to connect.

Comment: Refer to Compass documentation for how to provide the CA cert (probably via a URI option).

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the CA certificate to s_client, unless the certificate was issued by a well-known CA and its CA cert is in the bundle that ships with openssl (assuming such a bundle even exists).

Use `-CApath` or `-CAfile` options to specify the CA certificate.

Comment: I updated my original post... I shoved the whole cert chain into the mongodb01.pem... now its just complaining its self signed. I did trust the CA and intermediate CA on my PC, but Compass still complains.

Answer (score 0):

openssl does not usually have any default root certification authorities.

Try passing your CA with the `-CAfile` option, like

```
openssl s_client -CAfile mongodb.pem -connect mongodb01.orionsoftware.com:27017
```

Note that mongodb.pem should not contain the private key for this usage.

Comment: Hi Joe, I did make some progress and edited the post.